# Defining stopping time without making use of filtrations

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am currently writing a document in which I want to make use of the concept of a "stopping time" but avoiding a digression into the concept of a "filtration." Is the following definition correct?

Let $\{ X_t \}_{t \ge 0}$ be a stochastic process. A stopping time with respect to $\{ X_t \}_{t \ge 0}$ is a random variable $\tau \ge 0$ such that if one conditions on the collection of random variables $\{ X_t \}_{0 \leq t \leq T}$ for some $T \geq 0$ then $\mathbb{1}(\tau \leq T)$ is independent of the random variables $\{ X_t \}_{t > T}$ (where $\mathbb{1}$ is an indicator function).

Comment: I don't think so. Consider $\tau$ to be independent of $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$.

Comment: Would that not be a stopping time?

Comment: If $\tau$ is a stopping time with respect to $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ then for any $T$ we have 
$$\{\tau \leq T\} \in \sigma (X_t \: | \: t \leq T) \subseteq \sigma(X_t \: | \: t\geq 0)$$
But if $\tau$ is also independent of $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ that would imply that the event $\{\tau \leq T\}$ is independent of itself implying that $\mathbb{P}(\tau \leq T) \in \{0,1\}$. So $\tau$ would be constant.

Comment: Is it the case that if I condition on $\{ X_t \}_{0 \leq t \leq T}$ then $\mathbb{1}_{\tau \leq T}$ is deterministic?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case. And also a decent way to avoid speaking of filtrations.